# i am trying to install xdebug on windows 8 and iis 8

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, netbeans

I am using PHP Version 5.4.14

and I cannot install xdebug

```
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: CGI/FastCGI
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.14
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.4\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\php
```

This is my php.ini

```
[Xdebug]
;zend_extension= C:\php\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-nts-x86_64.dll
zend_extension= C:\php\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host= localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

I have tried version 2.2.3 and 2.2.2 of without success

I am not using `apache`; I am using `iis 8 on windows 8

netbeans its installed working with codeigniter 
when i try to debug its always like this

Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your phpinfo() say about xdebug?
Is it only the debuggin that doesn't work? Or how are errors treated?

Comment: phpinfo says that xdebug its not installed

Comment: Paste your phpinfo() to here, and follow those instructions: http://xdebug.com/wizard.php

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get XDebug working on IIS 10 on Windows 10 x64 with PHP 7.1 as follows:

Launch a command prompt as administrator and type the following:

```
php -i > C:\php.txt
```

Go to https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and paste in the contents of C:\php.txt.

Follow the instructions as to which version of XDebug to download and note the line it tells you to add to your php.ini file.

My PHP.ini looks like this (I manually entered this info):

```
[XDebug]
; XDEBUG Extension
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-7.1-vc14- nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
```

Back in the command prompt type **IISRESET** to restart IIS and cause PHP to reload.

Comment: This got me up and running in ~2 minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Richard Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576518/richard-moore). Your info to try **php -i > C:\php.txt** helped me get XDebug installed.

The problem was that the dll could not be found. Even though
https://xdebug.org/wizard.php instructed me to use a relative path.

> PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension
>   'ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll' (tried:
>   ext\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll (The specified module
>   could not be found.),
>   ext\php_ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll.dll (The
>   specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0